# Two quick notation questions about $M_X(t)$ the Moment Generating Function

Tags: probability, notation, moment-generating-functions, expected-value

> The Moment Generating function of $X$, $M_X(t)$ is defined as
>
> $$M_X(t) = E[e^{tX}] = 1 + tE[X] + \frac{t^2 E[X^2]}{2!} + ... $$

**Question 1** Is the MGF a function of one or two variables (as in $t$ or $t$ and $X$)?

**Question 2** I know this probably looks dumb but why would it not be $M(t,X)$ or $M_{t,X}(t,X)$?

---

For example in the law of the unconscious statistician $E[g(X)]$ is a function of $X$. So maybe $E[e^{tX}]$ could be thought of as $E[g(X,t)]$.

I don't think $f(x,y)$ is equivalent to $f_X(y)$ at all since one is the joint pdf and the other is the marginal pdf.

**Reason I'm asking** is because I'm learning about MGFs and want to understand the elementary stuff... thanks for your help I know this is not a very inspired question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MGF is the expectation of a function of a random variable, thus cannot depend on any realizations of that random variable--that is to say, it is **not** a function of $X$.  It is a function of $t$, as well as any **parameters** of the distribution of $X$.

> For example in the law of the unconscious statistician $E[g(X)]$ is a function of $X$.

This is not a correct statement.  Why do you think this is true?

For example, suppose $X \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$.  Then $$\Pr[X = 1] = p, \quad \Pr[X = 0] = 1-p.$$  It follows that $$M_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tX}] = e^0 \cdot \Pr[X = 0] + e^t \cdot \Pr[X = 1] = (1-p) + e^t p = (e^t - 1)p + 1.$$  Note there is no $X$ in the result, only $t$ and the parameter $p$.

Comment: Crap you're right... I've been spending a lot of time the past few days learning about conditional expectation on another RV like $E[Y|X]$ or $E[g(X)|X]$ that I'm tripping over myself. I will need to meditate on your answer but it helps a lot thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The MGF is a function of one variable, depending on the distribution of the random variable $X$.  It isn't a function of $X$ (i.e. the value of the random variable).  Same for $E(g(X))$.

Comment: Thank you Robert this is helpful for me. Looking again at the MGFs of a bunch of distributions (Bernoulli, Poisson, etc) it's clear that as you said theyr'e all functions of one variable.